# Doctrine postPersist Event deprecated getEntity function

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In Symfony after creating a Doctrine `postPersist` EventListener, my IDE pointed to the `$args->getEntity()` line; As being deprecated, I do not know how I can remedy this because it is the same code as in the [Symfony docs for version 2.8](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Screenshot from IDE PhpStorm:  https://image.prntscr.com/image/tT4zAlXkQMOxqvo6TLblUg.png

Code:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your eventlistener class in use, i guess you set the bad class.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs; -> the getEntity() method is deprecated.
```

You should use :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$args->getObject()` instead, it returns the same object as `getEntity()`.

More info : http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Persistence.Event.LifecycleEventArgs.html#70-78

If you use Doctrine < 2.4, you should use `Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs`

Comment: Not exactly, the method `getUnitOfWork()` doesn't exist on getObject()